# Turn off gitgutter within vimrc

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I've installed [gitgutter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-gitgutter)
and want to have it off by default.
The documentation says use

> :GitGutterDisable

to do this. And if I'm in a vim session this works. However I want to add this to my vimrc to make it permanent.

I've tried adapting other plugin commands within vimrc such as

```
let g:GitGutterDisable
```

and various other combinations but can't get the damn thing to turn off. 
I also looked in *~/.vim/bundle/vim-gitgutter/plugin/gitgutter.vim* and fiddled with a few settings there.

I got close with setting the below to zero

```
call s:set('g:gitgutter_enabled',                     1)
```

but this just permanently turned it off, ie  :GitGutterSignsToggle on the vim command line no longer worked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your vimrc loads before any plugins are available. That means, that commands, that are defined by plugins are not yet defined. Therefore, I would advise to use the *VimEnter* autocommand like this:

```
:au VimEnter * :GitGutterDisable
```

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing, from https://vimawesome.com/plugin/vim-gitgutter

> To turn off vim-gitgutter by default
>
> Add `let g:gitgutter_enabled = 0` to your ~/.vimrc.

For example in ~/.vimrc on systems that don't have `git` I use

```
if executable('git')
   let g:gitgutter_highlight_lines = 1  " Turn on gitgutter highlighting
else
    let g:gitgutter_git_executable = '/bin/true'
    let g:gitgutter_enabled = 0
endif
```

Comment: if you disable it, why do you set the git executable to `true`?

Comment: Unfortunately if gitgitter doesn't find something to execute it emits an error every time vim starts "vim-gitgutter: cannot find git. Please set g:gitgutter_git_executable."  So by setting the git executable to "/bin/true" no errors are emitted and vim starts up without error.

Comment: It does even if `g:gitgutter_enabled` has been set? that sounds like a bug to me.